# Comparing type of literal in swift fails?

Tags: swift, reflection, swift3

This code works is Swift 3:

```
let a = 1
type(of: a) == Int.self // true
```

However, remarkably this code fails:

```
// error: binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Int.Type' operands
type(of: 1) == Int.self
```

What is the syntax to make the second comparison work, if any?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Interestingly, `let type1 = type(of: 1);type1 == Int.self` works

Comment: One solution could be to initialize an Integer like this
`type(of: Int(1)) == Int.self // returns true`
I don't know why this is necessary, though

Comment: Weirdly, printing `b` in `let b = type(of: 1)` prints Int.

Comment: This is probably to do with the fact that `type(of:)` is not an actual function call, only an expression. Regardless, you should [file a bug](https://bugs.swift.org). Another variant to make it work: `type(of: 1 as Int) == Int.self`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error message was misleading. The real issue was how to interpret the literal `1` in the second call. Swift defaults to an `Int` when you define a variable:

```
let a = 1 // a is an Int
```

But the compiler can read it as `Double`, `UInt32`, `CChar`, etc. depending on the context:

```
func takeADouble(value: Double) { ... }
func takeAUInt(value: UInt) { ... }

takeADouble(value: 1) // now it's a Double
takeAUInt(value: 1)   // now it's a UInt
```

`type(of:)` is [defined](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2831805-type) as a generic function:

```
func type<Type, Metatype>(of: Type) -> Metatype
```

The compiler has no clue on how to interpret the `Type` generic parameter: should it be an `Int`, `UInt`, `UInt16`, etc.? Here's the error I got from the IBM Swift Sandbox:

```
Overloads for '==' exist with these partially matching parameter lists
(Any.Type?, Any.Type?), (UInt8, UInt8), (Int8, Int8),
(UInt16, UInt16), (Int16, Int16), (UInt32, UInt32), ...
```

You can give the coompiler some help by tell it what type it is:

```
type(of: 1 as Int) == Int.self
```

Comment: `type(of:)` is defined as a generic function, but it's not actually called directly – it's handled as a special case by the type-checker ([as per the comment in the implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Builtin.swift#L738)). Therefore this is likely just a type-checker bug. There should be no ambiguity with the literal because, as you say, it will default to `Int` when lacking no other type information, which is clearly the case here.